# Rasberry Pi - Start a SCREEN session then attach to it, so its displayed on the HDMI output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, screen

I can write a startup script that can start a screen session, however I couldn't find a guide, for starting the screen session, then attach to it, like so the particular screen session is displayed on the HDMI output after startup.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "session is displayed on the HDMI output"? Do you want to run terminal emulator with `screen` after X started and attach `screen` to existing session created by another system service?

Comment: I want to achieve the same result, if with a keyboard connected to my pi i would type `screen -S main_terminal` , so this screen session is being displayed on the HDMI output. But this should be automatic.